# Mididings on OS X

Tags: python, macos, midi, jack

I am having problems because [mididings](http://das.nasophon.de/mididings/) requires [jack](http://jackaudio.org/). I've installed it according to the instructions for OS X, but `setup.py` keeps complaining while building that it's not there. Running `jack` however shows that jack is indeed installed. Did I do something wrong? How would I be able to fix this?